# Boo/C#: Returning a collection performance

Tags: c#, performance, collections, return, boo

I have a function that gets a collection by reference, iterates over it, constructs a new collection of the same length containing updated structs, returns that collection (or rather a reference to it, since it's Boo/C# code).

I'm worried about performance of such a function. Is performance a lot worse than just updating the collection by reference? I need to call this function tens of times per second.

Thank you. Alisa.

P.S.: Why am I doing this? I'm trying to move onto functional programming and make it as pure as possible.

Comment: And you are worried because? Tens of times per second is not really that impressive. Have you reached a bottleneck? Just go along and worry about performance issues one you have those. In other words. do not go the path of premature optimization

Comment: I'm OCD, go figure, but thanks for reminding me of the dangers of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be slower, but not by much. It will also consume more memory as you'll have two collections in RAM whenever you're updating the structs.

The impact on performance will also be affected by your collections' sizes.

The best way to answer your question is to create both functions, then profile them.

Comment: Yes, what I'm worried the most about is scallability, but then again I can just rewrite it later if it becomes a problem. Thanks.